# C99 not default C- version for GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

Why does not GCC compile the C99 by default? I mean why is it necessary to add --std=c99 flag
everytime a code in C99 is written?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** As of GCC 5, `-std=gnu11` is the default. See [Porting to GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/porting_to.html).

---

See [C Dialect Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options), `gnu89` is the default.

> `gnu89'
>
> GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some
>   C99 features). This is the default for
>   C code.

As @tsv mentioned, ISO C99 is not fully supported yet:

> `c99'
>   `c9x'
>   `iso9899:1999'
>   `iso9899:199x'
>
> ISO C99. Note that this standard is not yet fully supported; see http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html for more information. The names `c9x' and `iso9899:199x' are deprecated.

And also:

> `gnu99'
>   `gnu9x'
>
> GNU dialect of ISO C99. When ISO C99 is fully implemented in GCC, this will become the default. The name `gnu9x' is deprecated.

Comment: gcc5 will use gnu11 as default version.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps because it still isn't fully implemented - see [C99 status](http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html).

It also could be argued C99 features haven't been widely adopted, although that's something of a circular argument.

Answer (score 10):

Use the command `c99` to compile C programs.

The current POSIX standard specifies the command `c99`, so it should be available in most Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that default configurations of gcc take a really long time to be changed, since every time a default configuration is changed, it can potentially break the compilation of valid programs (in this case valid c89 programs which are invalid in c99). Starting with gcc 5.0, the default C standard used by gcc will be gnu11, which is c11 with gnu extensions (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html)):

> The default mode for C is now -std=gnu11 instead of -std=gnu89.